# Recursion depth too shallow in Rust on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, rust

```
fn recu(n: int) {
    println!("{}", n);
    recu(n+1)
}

fn main() {
    recu(0)
}
```

Output :

```
...
2924
2925
2926
2927
2928
2929
2930
2931

thread '<main>' has overflowed its stack
[1]    23873 illegal hardware instruction  ./test
```

Infomation:

> rustc 1.0.0-nightly (ea6f65c5f 2015-01-06 19:47:08 +0000)
>
> MacBook Pro
>
> 2.2 GHz Intel Core i7

In other machine(Linux 64):

```
11668
11669
11670

thread '<main>' has overflowed its stack
[1]    18070 illegal hardware instruction (core dumped)  ./test
```

Comment: Not sure it's indeed the case. Maybe it's just that because of the crash, the standard output is not flushed, and it's only the first few thousand lines that are printed. Did you try flushing the standard output fully, after each call to println?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant I modified program, add `use std::io::stdio::flush;`, and flush in each recursion, but output remain (2687).

Comment: Any recursive algorithm that uses thousands of stack levels is the _exact wrong_ use case for recursion.

Comment: IIRC you can change the recursion depth with `#[recursion_depth(...)]` or something

Comment: @Manishearth, that's just the compiler's internal type-checking recursion limit. The runtime recursion depth is directly proportional to the size of the stack.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: This sounds more like a bug report, and not a question we can answer definitively here.

Comment: @dbaupp d'oh, right.

Comment: okey, I created an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice how 11670/2931 equals almost exactly 4 - that is, the number of stack frames on Linux is almost four times as many as on OS X. Apparently, your Mac OS X has 1/4 the default stack size of your Linux. This has nothing to do with Rust, an equivalent C program would produce roughly equal results. You can run `ulimit -s` from the command line to confirm the stack size difference between the OSes.

LLVM should be able to tail-call optimize this specific program however. Try running `rustc` with the `-O` flag. If this works, this will allow infinite recursion. LLVM will produce a `recu` function that instead of calling itself will loop back to its own start after setting `n`, allowing it to recurse without consuming stack space.

In my own tests, I had to modify the program to this in order to get it to recursive forever, probably because the `println!` macro hides destructors:

```
fn recu(n: int) {
    printint(n);
    recu(n+1)
}

#[inline(never)]
fn printint(n: int) {
    println!("{}", n);
}

fn main() {
    recu(0)
}
```